# cakephp find all record in group of member_id with order of id

Tags: mysql, cakephp

I want a cake php find query to find all record from comments table in order of id desc but all comments should be in group of member_id.

Suppose there are two Member with id 20 and 21 and last comment is by member with id 21. both member have posted multiple comments in different time.

So now i want all comments which are latest. means if latest comments is posted by member with id 21 then show all comments of member with id 21 and then all comments of another and so on.

I have tried group on member_id but it givs only single record for a member.

```
id  Member_id   comment
1   20           abc
2   21           abc
3   20           abc
4   20           abc
5   21           abc

id  Member_id   comment
5   21           Abc
2   21           Abc
4   20           Abc
3   20           abc
1   20           abc
```

its my records in table and i want like below

I want a cake php find query to find all record from comments table in order of id desc but all comments should be in group of member_id.

Suppose there are two Member with id 20 and 21 and last comment is by member with id 21. both member have posted multiple comments in different time.

So now i want all comments which are latest. means if latest comments is posted by member with id 21 then show all comments of member with id 21 and then all comments of another and so on.

I have tried group on member_id but it givs only single record for a member.

its my records in table and i want like below

here last comment is by member 21 so it will show all data of that member then member 20 and so on

Thanks

here last comment is by member 21 so it will show all data of that member then member 20 and so on

Thanks

Comment: In your question, provide sample data from your comments table AND what your expected output would be. (Your questions description is confusing - an example would help clarify.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't believe this can easily be done with one single query (that would convert simply to a `find`). I would use a two step process:

1. Get the most recent comment's member_id
2. Query all comments sorting
   based on that value.

Assuming this is written from the Comment model:

```
$lastCreated = $this->find('first', array(
        'order' => array('Comment.id' => 'desc')
    ));

$results = $this->find('all', array(
        'order' => array('Comment.member_id = ' . $lastCreated['Comment']['member_id']. ' desc'
                    ,'Comment.id' => 'desc')
    ));
```

---

The goal of the second find statement is have a SQL statement such as:

```
SELECT * 
FROM comments AS Comment
ORDER BY Comment.member_id = 21 desc
        ,Comment.id desc;
```

Comment: @Rakesh - I asked you for the example. Then I gave you a solution to that example . You need to give better example if you want a better solution.

Comment: I didn't find solution and then solve this problem by two time loop...first find all records of members and then find comments from member id